# Laravel 5.1 command bus no default mappings

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I'd like to get some informations about Laravel 5.1 command bus. As far as I see in 5.0 there was a BusServiceProvider in App/Providers namespace that provided some default behaviour for resolving command handler class so everything worked smoothly. But I created a project straight with 5.1 version and the file is not present in that version leaving commands created with

```
php artisan make:command --handler
```

useless if you don't map the command to handler manually or not create a self-handling command. Is that normal behaviour or there is something I am missing ?

Answer (score 1):

The command bus was deprecated in the move from 5.0 to 5.1; see [these](https://twitter.com/taylorotwell/status/569941495127547904) [tweets](https://twitter.com/laravelphp/status/609711855058026497) for more. They've been replaced with `Job`s, which can be run both synchronous or async.

Comment: This is something I don't understand, according to this link https://twitter.com/taylorotwell/status/570238860011008001 command bus is not deprecated, but still the  folder itself disappears and the commands becomes jobs now. And when you generate a job with artisan you can't generate it with handler so basically you are either going to use self-handling job or write your own stuff. Seems pretty messy ?